sed append a line to itself or awk $0 equivalent?
I have this text file containing a list like
name
surname
office
address
home_phone
office_phone
my_other_value

and I want to transform that to
'name':'Name';
'surname':'Surname';
'office':'Office';
'address':'Address';
'home_phone':'Home_Phone';
'office_phone':'Office_Phone';
'my_other_value':'My_Other_Value';

I tried to do that with a sed oneliner, I can change the case without problem with
sed -r 's/(\b|_)([a-z])/\1\U\2/g' /tmp/list

but how do you print the non modified line before itself like you would do a "print $0" with Awk?
I ended it doing like this but it's a bit dirty
while read line; do echo -ne "'$line':"; echo "'$line';" | sed -r 's/(\b|_)([a-z])/\1\U\2/g'; done < <(cat /tmp/list)
Tried some sed prints but without success.

Requiring the solution to be a oneliner is disingenuous. If it takes multiple lines, it's probably better for legibility to keep it that way.
Having said that,
sed -r -e "s/.*/'&'/" -e 'h;s/(\b|_)([a-z])/\1\U\2/g;x;G;s/\n/:/;s/$/;/' /tmp/list

seems to do what you are asking.
Breaking it up into smaller parts,

sed -r selects extended regular expression syntax. This isn't portable, but since you used it in your attempt, I kept it. (Try -E if you don't have -r; though that's not POSIX-portable, either.)
-e "s/.*/'&'/" performs a substitution to wrap the contents of the current input line inside literal single quotes, using double quotes around the script fragment to protect it from the shell.
-e '...' should perhaps be broken up into smaller parts. I mashed them together to make a oneliner. Equivalently you could replace each semicolon with ' -e ' and break up the script on multiple lines. This uses the stronger single quotes to avoid having to backslash-escape backslashes, dollar signs, etc which are special inside double quotes, but just themselves inside single quotes.

Let's break here to clarify a couple of concepts. sed commands operate on something called the pattern space, which usually contains the current input line; but as we will see below, you can change that. There is a second memory location called the hold space where you can store information which you need to refer back to later, as we soon will.

h copies the pattern space to the hold space. At this point, they both contain the input line with single quotes added around it.
s/(\b|_)([a-z])/\1\U\2/g is your original code to convert each word in the pattern space to proper case. This too uses some nonstandard facilities which are probably supported on Linux / GNU sed but not generally portable to other platforms.
x swaps the hold space (the original) with the pattern space (the proper-cased version). This is so that the append we do next appends the modified version after the original, rather than vice versa.
G appends the hold space to the end of the pattern space, separated by a newline.
s/\n/:/ replaces that newline with a colon.
s/$/;/ adds a semicolon at the end.

Demo: https://ideone.com/wNjvxA
If you need a properly portable solution, I would go with Awk. Somewhat ironically, a Perl or Python implementation might be quite portable in practice, although of course POSIX does not say anything about either of those (or Ruby, Haskell, Rust, Go, etc).

Damn, that's much more complicated than expected. Thanks for your answer!

Worthy of the nod for the excellent explanation alone.

My first instinct, too, was "use the hold space".  That's an important concept to any sed programmer.  At this point, I would lean towards storing the sed program in a file, rather than as multiple -e arguments (that also gives you opportunity to comment it better, too).

Using any awk:
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="_" }
    {
        orig = $0
        split(toupper($0),uc)
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            $i = substr(uc[i],1,1) substr($i,2)
        }
        printf "\047%s\047:\047%s\047;\n", orig, $0
    }
' file
'name':'Name';
'surname':'Surname';
'office':'Office';
'address':'Address';
'home_phone':'Home_Phone';
'office_phone':'Office_Phone';
'my_other_value':'My_Other_Value';

Like with any script you can cram it all onto 1 line if you find that useful for some reason:
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {orig=$0; split(toupper($0),uc); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=substr(uc[i],1,1) substr($i,2); printf "\047%s\047:\047%s\047;\n", orig, $0}' file


++ it is much more readable in awk than a long cryptic sed command

I'll gladly second that. Well done -- again Ed!

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed "s/.*/'&';/;h;s/[a-z]\+/\u&/g;H;g;s/;\n/:/" file

Since single quotes occur in this problem to avoid '\'' quoting, surround the sed solution commands by double quotes.
Using substitution surround the line by single quotes and append a semicolon.
Make a copy and store it in the hold space.
Uppercase the first of a group of lowercase characters globally throughout the line.
Append this to the copy in the hold space and replace the current line by the contents of hold space.
Substitute the introduced semi-colon and newline by a colon.

An even easier solution:
 sed "s/[^_]\+/\u&/g;s/.*/\L'&'\E:'&';/" file


Oh quite nice - bravo! Nothing like a little manipulation of the pattern and hold spaces along with the & portion of pattern space matched to spice things up.

A Ruby:
ruby -lne 'puts "\047#{$_}\047:\047#{$_.split(/(_)/).
                     map(&:capitalize).join}\047;"' file 

Or this Perl:
perl -lnE 'say "\047$_\047:\047",map {ucfirst $_} split /(_)/, $_."\047;"' file

Either prints:
'name':'Name';
'surname':'Surname';
'office':'Office';
'address':'Address';
'home_phone':'Home_Phone';
'office_phone':'Office_Phone';
'my_other_value':'My_Other_Value';

The main challenge here is printing ' when the shell really wants to keep single quotes for its own use. To get around that (in Ruby or other command line compiled scripts) you can use the \047 representation of ' which the shell does not care about.

Quite nice as well. Three different interpreters no less.

You might want to review the OP's requirement as regards the last three examples.

Spot the difference OP's 'home_phone':'Home_Phone'; and yours  'home_phone':'Home_phone';

@potong: Yes, did not notice all words ucfirst... Fixed in Ruby...

sed with a loop:
sed -re 's/.*/&:&/' -e ':a;s/(.*):(.*)(\b|_)([a-z])/\1:\2\3\U\4/;ta' /tmp/list
# Or shorter
sed -re 's/.*/&:&/;:a;s/(.*:.*)(\b|_)([a-z])/\1\2\U\3/;ta'/tmp/list

First change input to
name:name
surname:surname
office:office
address:address
home_phone:home_phone
office_phone:office_phone
my_other_value:my_other_value

Next replace one lowercase character after the : each time before returning to anchor :a.
EDIT:
Two strange/ugly alternatives:
You can also use the execute option for nesting two sed commands.
sed -r 's/.*/printf "%s:" "&"; printf "%s\n" "&" | sed -r "s#(^|_)([a-z])#\\1\\U\\2#g"/e' /tmp/list

Or you can replace everything first and repair before the :.
sed -r 's/.*/&:&/;s/(\b|_)([a-z])/\1\U\2/g;s/([^:]*):/\L&/' /tmp/list
# or shorter
sed -r 's/.*/&:&/;s/(\b|_)([a-z])/\1\U\2/g;s/.*:/\L&/' /tmp/list


Regarding

how do you print the non modified line before itself like you would do
a "print $0" with Awk?

GNU sed has p command which does Print the pattern space. consider following simple example, let file.txt content be
able
baker
charlie

then
sed -e 'p' -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/' file.txt

gives output
able
ABLE
baker
BAKER
charlie
CHARLIE

as you can observe there is newline between original and altered line, which is consistent with print $0 in GNU AWK with default settings.
(tested in GNU sed 4.8)

Nice effort! is able and baker supposed to be the phonetics for alpha, bravo, charlie, delta, echo,...?

@DavidC.Rankin Able, Baker, Charlie... is so-called Allied phonetic alphabet, for full alphabet see https://www.history.navy.mil/research/library/online-reading-room/title-list-alphabetically/p/phonetic-alphabet-and-signal-flags.html

Ahah! A mix of the 1913, 1927 and WWII phonetics. Cool page. Glad I never had to learn the signal flags...
